# Shortest path with ArangoDB & Java

Tags: java, arangodb

I read in the documentation that ArangoDB is migrating functions from AQL to native.
I was trying the [shortest path example](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/Manual/Graphs/GeneralGraphs/Functions.html#shortestpath):

```
ArangoDB arangoDB = new ArangoDB.Builder().build();
ArangoGraph g = arangoDB.db().graph("routeplanner");
```

Can I continue implementing without using AQL like in the shell example? How can I do?

*PS: Are edges bidirectional? Can I go [from Cologne to Hamburg](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/Manual/Graphs/GeneralGraphs/Functions.html)?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph functions are only accessible over the arango shell or foxx services. They aren't provided by the HTTP API which is used by the Java driver.

When using the Java driver (or any other driver) you have to use AQL for shortest path or other graph functionality from the [docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/Manual/Graphs/GeneralGraphs/Functions.html).

Edges in ArangoDB are always directional (an edge document always has the fields "_from", "_to") but you can define the direction edges are followed in the query within it (see [docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/AQL/Graphs/ShortestPath.html#syntax)).

```
FOR v, e
  IN ANY SHORTEST_PATH
  'germanCity/Cologne' TO 'germanCity/Hamburg'
  GRAPH 'routeplanner'
  OPTIONS {weightAttribute:'distance'}
  RETURN [v._key, e._key]
```